# on my android app,Why my notification only can hear sound and vibrate but can not show on status bar

Tags: android

I have a method to show notificaton in my service class when have new message come in. but when it was invoked,it works, but only can hear the sound and vibrate and can not see it shows on the status bar. and I put the method on a demo app, it work well. Some body can help me, thankfull

Comment: post your code so we can what's wrong with your implementation

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
  private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, <nameofactivity>.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer,But it not the reason of my problem. and I have find the reason of it. some android deveic permit users to  check off show notification in setting/aap info of you apk,and the check off state will be save into system info by method setNotificationsEnabledForPackage(String pkg, boolean enabled) {..} with the key of you app packet name,so event if uninstall the apk,next time reinstall,it will keep the state off which have bean setted.so if someone run into the problem like me,go to settings/app find you apk,check the show notification state enable.